# How to split screen in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image]
I want to split my screen like this, first on half(0.5f of whole screen), then this half on other half(0.25f of whole screen), and then again to split it on half(0.125f), but when do it, it overlaps one of the screens and is not splited as expected

```
 Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter) {
        MapLoad()
        //0.5f of screen
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = Purple200)
        ) {

            //0.25f
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(color = NotFoundLabel)
            ) {
                //0.125f
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(color = LightBlue)
                ) {

                    Text("SOME TEXT ONE",Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color = Color.Red))
                }
                //0.125f
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
                        .background(color = Color.Cyan)
                ) {
                    Text("SOME TEXT TWO",Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color = Color.White))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The strange thing is when I change last column with cyan color .fillMaxHeight(0.5f) to 1f it fill the whole half of the space.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show a picture of what exactly you want it to look like.

Comment: Use `weight` ;)

Comment: Stephen Veniouze it worked, but why it is not working other way? What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Modifier.fillMaxHeight` takes part of the size available at the time of view measuring.

When you're using two of these, at first view takes the half size available, and the second one takes half of what's left.

You can use `Modifier.fillMaxHeight(1f)` for the second view, but using `Modifier.weight(1f)` for both seems clearer.